# How to create a $_SESSION variable and then carry it over to another page

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to create a session variable so I can use it on another page. (Like make the session variable on page1.php and then call it again on `page2.php`).

edit : What I meant by Form validation was making sure that the variables were set (like there was something in the input box) and then make them session variables so I could use them on other pages.

Here is my code for `page1.php`:

```
<?php 

session_start();


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php 

 if(!isset($_POST["submit"])) {

 //matri70boss suggested this code. Thanks matri70boss! 
 if(!empty($_POST) && empty($_POST['username']){
  echo "error , username was not submited";
 } else {
  $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
 }

 }

 ?>

 <title>NoterSharp</title>
 <link rel="icon" href="Images/icon.png">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

 </head>

 <body>

 <div id="header">

 <h1 id="header">Welcome to NoterSharp!<h1>

 <form action="page2.php" method="post">

 <input type="username" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

 </form>


 </div>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Here is my `page2.php` code:

```
<?php 
session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>NoterSharp</title>
<link rel="icon" href="Images/icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="output">

Your username is: <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

For some reason the username isn't being displayed on page2.php

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “form validation” Are you wanting to check for blank fields?

Comment: fix this line $_SESSION["username"] == $_POST["username"]; to $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];

Comment: What I meant by Form validation was making sure that the variables were set (like there was something in the input box) and then make them session variables so I could use them on other pages.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas Aoki, I'll fix that.

Comment: Your input fields don't have `name`s. And your form has `page2` as its action, so `$_POST` won't ever be filled in `page1`.

Comment: TiiJ7, I thought name and id were the same. I'll add name's to the inputs.

Comment: TiiJ7. About the form action, How can I make so that the $_POST is filled in page1 and is then carried over to page2?

Answer (score 0):

change
     $_SESSION["username"] == $_POST["username"];
to

```
$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
```

and maybe add something like

```
    if(!empty($_POST) && empty($_POST['username']){
      echo "error , username was not submited";
    }
```

to check if it the username was sent , which would echo "error , ..." in case the form was submited but username is empty (either empty string or not set).
Maybe set the  $_SESSION["username"] in the else such as

```
    if(!empty($_POST) && empty($_POST['username']){
      echo "error , username was not submited";
    } else {
      $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for more information you can use the below links as reference. :)

```
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-sessions-and-session-variables-in-php--cms-31839
https://www.w3schools.com/pHp/php_sessions.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php
```